# anaconda not installing packages correctly

Tags: module, package, jupyter, libraries, arcgis

So i JUST want to install and use packages without any problems.

**What i need:**
To use Jupyter and import the package "arcgis"

**The problem:**
when i do a conda install the arcgis package goes to:
C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\pkgs\arcgis-1.5.1-py36h78dcb7a_1

instead of where its supposed to go (as ive been told) to

C:\Users\ME\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

SO,
when i try to import the package it says it doesnt exist

**ive tried:**
using - sys.path.insert to just retrieve the package in the current working environment but if i do that then im skipping files in other places. Because although i dont get an error... nothing is produced as an output.

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, '/Users/ME/Jupyter_Projects/My_stuff/arcgis-1.5.1-py36h78dcb7a_1/Lib/site-packages')

from arcgis import GIS

gis = GIS()

pdx_map = gis.map('Australia')

pdx_map
```

Thanks for any help anyone can provide. but please for any answers that you speak in really basic language and dont assume that i know anything. People usually answer to me with things completely out of context like 
$ ........
i dont know if '$' means the command prompt or Pycharm or what so please explain where ur working when u answer. im using Jupyter, so unless stated otherwise ill assume any answer is in either Jupyter or just folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem just now

**The solution:**
i went into conda and I used 'cd' to go to my working directory where packages should be (C:\My directory\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages) 
[C:\users\Me> cd Anaconda3\lib\site-packages]

i then installed arcgis through conda at that directory

**Anaconda command prompt**

C:\My directory\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages> conda install -c esri arcgis

then i went into normal command prompt and enabled the jupyter extension

C:\users\me> jupyter nbextension enable arcgis --py --sys-prefix

then i imported a map normally and it works now

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
my_gis.map()
```

**MAP OF EARTH APPEARS HERE**

**Usually the answer is simpler than you think, go figure**